# What is a good alternative for openinviter in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a feature that will import contacts of a user from different sites as choosen by user like gmail,yahoo,facebook etc. I found [Django openinviter](https://github.com/tschellenbach/DjangoOpenInviter) which was a django app written over openinviter api but my requirement was authentication for importing contacts should be done like oauth i.e we should not ask password from user. So anyone can please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com).  We have a great widget that makes integration extremely easy (5 minute copy/paste job) and an API if you want to make the user interface different from how the widget looks.

Comment: Its API was good and easy but it has limited options to import contacts and it is only free for 30-days. anyways thanks for you valuable suggestion.